# If points equal value: reset to zero

Tags: userpoints

I use the [User Points](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module. I've set a rule that add 10 points per content viewed. This was easy. THEN I want to check if user points is greater than 100 and, if it is, send an email to admin, AND set points to that user back to zero.

Comment: How do you interact with User Points to add points?

Answer (score 2):

Download the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module and import the following rule:

```
{ "rules_reset_points" : {
    "LABEL" : "Reset points",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Points" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "userpoints_event_points_awarded_after" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "global $user;\r\n$num_pts = userpoints_get_current_points($user-\u003Euid, \u0027all\u0027);\r\nif ($num_pts \u003E 100) {return TRUE;}" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "userpoints-transaction:user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "loaded_points" : "Number of points in the specified category." } }
        }
      },
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : { "input_1" : [ "loaded-points" ], "op" : "*", "input_2" : "-1" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "result" : "Calculation result" } }
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "userpoints-transaction:user" ],
          "points" : [ "result" ],
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Prevent more than 100 points.",
          "operation" : "Add",
          "display" : 0,
          "moderate" : "approved"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adapt the actions to your needs, add another action "Send mail" after installing the [Mime mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module ([this article](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-html-emails-drupal-7-using-rules) may help you in doing that) and you're done!

Comment: Rules module is Duck Programming. Beware. http://workshop.unspace.ca/post/67567487259/duck-programming

Comment: @matt2000 Beware of what, exactly? If you're going to make sweeping statements like that you should have something to back it up. How do you respond to the conclusion of the post you linked to, which reads, verbatim, _The project described should not discourage anyone from contemplating building a system around rules engines, programmable workflow or domain-specific languages._? What's your preferred alternative to provide this level of configurability to an application? I'm not being confrontational in case it sounds like that, I just don't understand your objection

Comment: I endorse Anil's solution, because I prefer a small bit of simple code, over a dependency on a complex rules-engine. But "Beware" means "be careful," not "absolutely do not." My only strong objection against Rules module is to using it without Features module or something equivalent, and version control, so that rules are unambiguously documented in code. Sometimes it is the best tool for the job, but it's a dangerous tool if wielded without concern for the complexity you are adding to your application. For example, errors in Rules can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

- User hook_userpoints($op, $params = array())

  Use this hook to act upon certain operations. When other modules award
  points to a user, your hook will be called, among others.
- $op = "points after"
- Read user points and check for > 100 condition
- Use userpoints_userpointsapi() to reset points
- Deduct 100 points

  $params = array (
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'points' => -100,
  );
  userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
- Send Email to admin using [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7)
- Above functions has been clearly explained in Readme.txt file inside module folder.